# Finding very specific values within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have this text file with a wide variety of text.

```
SETUP - BALANCE MODE PREFERENCE ORDER 3RD CHOICE: HEBM_TapeTape
SETUP - ALLOW SINGLE WEIGHT ALONG PROFILE: no
SETUP - ALLOW OPTICAL SPOKE CALCULATIONS: no
Number of spokes used for this spin: 0
spoke locations: 
spoke base widths (enc cnts): 
spoke base widths       (mm): 
Spokes were entered manually: no

Weight 0: 2.25oz
    Is3DWeightValueNonZero: yes
    Plane Type: HEPT_Inner
    Weight type: HEWT_Tape
    Weight width: 18.000000 mm
    Weight height: 3.810000 mm
    IsSplitWeight: no
    IsSpokeWeight: no
    Is3MStyleTapeWeight: no
    Weight-circle distance: 192.340000 mm
    Weight-circle radius: 194.310000 mm
    Number of tape weight Rows: 1
    Number of tape weight chiclets last row: 9
    Max number of tape weight chiclets per row: 12
    Tape menu selection in use: 0
    Tape sub-menu selection in use: 0
Weight 1: NA
    Is3DWeightValueNonZero: 
    Plane Type: 
    Weight type: 
    Weight width:
    Weight height:
    IsSplitWeight: 
    IsSpokeWeight: 
    Is3MStyleTapeWeight: 
    Weight-circle distance:
    Weight-circle radius:
    Number of tape weight Rows:
    Number of tape weight chiclets last row:
    Max number of tape weight chiclets per row:
    Tape menu selection in use:
    Tape sub-menu selection in use:
Weight 2: 2.00oz
    Is3DWeightValueNonZero: yes
    Plane Type: HEPT_Outer
    Weight type: HEWT_Tape
    Weight width: 18.000000 mm
    Weight height: 3.810000 mm
    IsSplitWeight: no
    IsSpokeWeight: no
    Is3MStyleTapeWeight: no
    Weight-circle distance: 302.340000 mm
    Weight-circle radius: 193.040000 mm
    Number of tape weight Rows: 1
    Number of tape weight chiclets last row: 8
    Max number of tape weight chiclets per row: 12
    Tape menu selection in use: 0
    Tape sub-menu selection in use: 0
```

etc..

I have to find the measurement after weight (The measurement can be after any of the weights used as a header such as 2.25) and store them into a variable. What is the best way to extract the float value after the word weight(0-4). The document changes length between different saves of and the values can be after any one of the weight subheads. I currently store each text file in an array like this:

```
readWeights = File.OpenText(siteChosen + Storage[Counter] + sWeightsFrstPresFile);
sCopyWeightsFile = readWeights.ReadToEnd();
sWeightsFirstPresented = sCopyWeightsFile.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I have tried splitting the array then searching for the "oz" keyword but it does not seem to find it.
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Question - Is your file layout formatted like it's shown above?

Comment: you should probably just read in all the lines into a List<T>, iterate the List<T> and check for if that line `.Contains("Weight") from there you want to do `IndexOf(":")` and return the position, using then the SubString Function too return the rest of the value from that line.. this is actually not that difficult.. I would create a Class that Mimics the Datastructure of your datafile also since you have weight in your data I would check to see if the next line has the value containing `Is3DWeightValueNonZero` if so then you can skip using a for loop you would use the `continue;` key word

Comment: Yeah its formatted just like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your array by using `List<string>` or just the plain array that you've split. Search for your text in these array elements.  Build out a new `List<string>` with the ones that contain "oz".

```
var myList = new List<string>();

for (var i = 0; i < sWeightsFirstPresented.length; i++)
{
    if (sWeightsFirstPresented[i].IndexOf("oz") > -1)
        myList.Add(sWeightsFirstPresented[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` to read the file. This however may not work if you have line feed characters within the text fields.

Then you can use a simple regex like this to identify weights.

```
var weights = list.Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, @"[Weight] \d")).Select(w => w.Split(new[] {':'})[1]).ToList();
```